# htaccess - rewrite rule to get end of url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url which ends with a certain variable string, and was erroneously generated and indexed unfortunately.

Example:
http://domain.com/anything-in-between/?var=xyz-abc-abc-abc

How can I redirect to main site (kill it), by detecting 'abc-abc-abc' using htaccess?

Why wouldn't this work and what would be the best solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} abc-abc-abc
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the query string as claesv suggests but you need to then kill the query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bvar=.*?abc-abc-abc$
RewriteRule ^               index.php?           [L]
```

This will do it silently (i.e. in the server as an internal redirect and not involving the browser).  You can't use 301s reliably to trim query strings.

Comment: How about if I want to respond with a 404? I read responding with a customised 404 might be better for SEO, in terms of removing pages that are really 'dead' or shouldn't be there.

Comment: I figured, just send to non-existent page. The only other change I needed was to not use "\" but use "^" as per claesv solution.

Comment: @bcm, just swap the [L] flag for an [F] one.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=.*abc-abc-abc$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```